# Can I override a class function without creating a new class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, object, polymorphism, overriding

I'm making a game in pygame and I have made an 'abstract' class that's sole job is to store the sprites for a given level (with the intent of having these level objects in a list to facilitate the player being moved from one level to another)

Alright, so to the question.  If I can do the equivalent of this in Python(code curtesy of Java):

```
Object object = new Object (){
    public void overriddenFunction(){
        //new functionality
        };
    };
```

Than when I build the levels in the game I would simply have to override the constructor (or a class/instance method that is responsible for building the level) with the information on where the sprites go, because making a new class for every level in the game isn't that elegant of an answer.  Alternatively I would have to make methods within the level class that would then build the level once a level object is instantiated, placing the sprites as needed.

So, before one of the more stanch developers goes on about how anti-python this might be (I've read enough of this site to get that vibe from Python experts) just tell me if its doable.

Comment: when you say "'abstract' class" do you mean you actually used `abc.ABCMeta` and `abc.abstractmethod` or you did something all your own here

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong. But yeah that actually creates a class an anonymous class.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can!

```
class Foo:
    def do_other(self):
        print('other!')
    def do_foo(self):
        print('foo!')


def do_baz():
    print('baz!')

def do_bar(self):
    print('bar!')

# Class-wide impact
Foo.do_foo = do_bar
f = Foo()
g = Foo()
# Instance-wide impact
g.do_other = do_baz

f.do_foo()  # prints "bar!"
f.do_other()  # prints "other!"

g.do_foo()  # prints "bar!"
g.do_other()  # prints "baz!"
```

> So, before one of the more stanch developers goes on about how anti-python this might be

Overwriting functions in this fashion (if you have a good reason to do so) seems reasonably pythonic to me.  An example of one reason/way for which you might have to do this would be if you had a dynamic feature for which static inheritance didn't or couldn't apply.

The case against might be found in the Zen of Python:

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Readability counts.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: You've overridden the class method (`Foo.do_foo`), so if I do `g = Foo()` and invoke `g.do_foo()` that will also print `bar`.  Might be what the OP wants, not really sure whether he wants overrides per *instance* or per *class*...

Comment: Indeed, that's the intent of my example.  Title says 'class function' so that's what I went with.

Comment: It might not be pythonic (I'm mainly a Java dev) but it's really useful for creating a tree structure with an `isChildGivenCriteria(criteria)` function and for the root node, overriding it with an "everything is my child" `return True` function

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's doable.  Here, I use `functools.partial` to get the implied `self` argument into a regular (non-class-method) function:

```
import functools

class WackyCount(object):
    "it's a counter, but it has one wacky method"
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s = %d' % (self.name, self.value)
    def incr(self):
        self.value += 1
    def decr(self):
        self.value -= 1
    def wacky_incr(self):
        self.value += random.randint(5, 9)

# although x is a regular wacky counter...
x = WackyCount('spam', 1)
# it increments like crazy:
def spam_incr(self):
    self.value *= 2
x.incr = functools.partial(spam_incr, x)

print (x)
x.incr()
print (x)
x.incr()
print (x)
x.incr()
print (x)
```

and:

```
$ python2.7 wacky.py
spam = 1
spam = 2
spam = 4
spam = 8
$ python3.2 wacky.py    
spam = 1
spam = 2
spam = 4
spam = 8
```

---

Edit to add note: this is a *per-instance* override.  It takes advantage of Python's attribute look-up sequence: if `x` is an instance of class `K`, then `x.attrname` starts by looking at `x`'s dictionary to find the attribute.  If not found, the next lookup is in `K`.  All the normal class functions are actually `K.func`.  So if you want to replace the *class* function dynamically, use @Brian Cane's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a different class, via inheritance, for each level.

But you might get some mileage out of copy.deepcopy() and monkey patching, if you're really married to treating Python like Java.