# Using setattr() to overload a method in an already existing class definition

Tags: python, overloading

I was wondering if it is possible to add a method to an existing class, overloading an already existing method. I know, that I can use setattr() to add a function to a class, however overloading does not work.

As an example I would like to add to the class

```
class foo:
    def hello(self):
        print("hello")
```

The following function, overloading "hello"

```
def hello2(self,baa):
    self.hello()
    print(str(baa))
```

it is clear that this works

```
setattr(foo,"hello2",hello2)    
test = foo()
test.hello()
test.hello2("bye")
```

but I would like to be able to call it like this

```
test.hello("bye")
```

Is there a possible way to do this? 
EDIT: Thank you all for your answers! It is important to me, that I can really overload, and not only replace the existing method. I changed my example to reflect that!

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I override a class function without creating a new class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757238/can-i-override-a-class-function-without-creating-a-new-class-in-python)

Comment: hmm not directly I am afraid, but i might just use inheritance to solve the issue, thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

```
class foo():
    def hello(self, baa=""):
        print("hello"+str(baa))


def main():
     test = foo()
     test.hello()
     test.hello("bye")
```

will output

`hello
hellobye`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually avoid using `setattr` here. Since you know the method you want to overload ahead of time, you can do:

```
def hello2(self, baa):
    print("hello"+str(baa))
```

followed by;

```
foo.hello = hello2
test = foo()
test.hello()
```