# Pythonic way to override a method from a parent class for any child class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class with some methods and some (potentially many) child classes which modify some aspects of the base class. Additionally, there is a common modification that I'd like to be able to apply to any of the child classes. This modification involves overriding a method. I feel like there should be a simple OOP approach to achieving this, but I don't know what it is.

Say I have a parent class (Base) and some child classes (A and B):

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        
    def go(self):
        self.x+=1
        
    def printme(self):
        print(f'x: {self.x}')
        
class A(Base): #subclasses Base
    def go(self):
        self.x-=1
        
class B(Base): #subclasses Base
    def go(self):
        self.x-=2

a = A()
b = B()
```

I want to be able to update the .printme() method of objects like `a` or `b`

but this doesn't work

```
def printme(self):
    print(f'modified printing of x: {self.x}')
a.printme = printme
a.printme() #raises TypeError: printme() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

(I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757426/6591124) solution but it seems hacky and I think there must be a better way.)

I also can't think of a way to use multiple inheritance: if I write a single subclass of Base with the updated printme() function, then I can't generate objects that have the go() methods of class `A` or `B` without writing separate subclasses for each of those.

After thinking about it for a while longer, I realized it would be possible to dynamically create a new subclass from any child class and override the method like this:

```
def with_mod(Class):
    class ClassWithMod(Class):
        def printme(self):
            print(f'new statement: {self.x}')
    return ClassWithMod

a = A()
a.printme() #prints "x: 0"

a_mod = with_mod(A)()
a_mod.printme() #prints "new statement: 0"
```

I tested this code and it works, but is this the "correct" approach or is there a more correct/pythonic OOP approach? What I don't like about this solution is that type(a_mod) is the generic ClassWithMod. I'd like it to still be of type A. (Maybe this means I want to override the method at the instance level rather than the class level?)

Comment: Are you looking for this: [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, you want to override the method but only for specific instances?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance .

Comment: yes, that solution will work for me. Thank you.